# How to get the full dataframe using lambda function in python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, lambda

I have a loop logic using iterrows but the performance is bad

```
result = []
for index, row in df_test.iterrows():
    result.append(product_recommendation_model.predict(df_test.iloc[[index]]))

submission = pd.DataFrame({'ID': df_test['ID'],
                           'Result': result
                          })

display(submission)
```

I would like to rewrite it with using **apply lambda** but I have no idea how to get the full data frame.

```
a = df_test.apply(lambda x: product_recommendation_model.predict(df_test.iloc[[x]]) ,axis=1)
```

Can anyone help me please? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I can run it with the below code.

```
df_test.apply(lambda i: product_recommendation_model.predict(i.to_frame().T), axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this works for you

```
df_new = df_test.apply(lambda row: pd.Series([row['ID'],product_recommendation_model.predict(row)] ,axis=1)
df_new.columns = ['ID','Result']
```

Note: You can also pass argument to your prediction like row[column_name] if you want to pass only one column value to predict, row will send all column values of a row.

Comment: Thanks, actuallyI need to pass the dataframe to product_recommendation_model.predict by each row of df_test as dataframe format. I have tried with your code like: df_test.apply(lambda row: pd.Series([row['ID'],product_recommendation_model.predict(row)] ,axis=1)) But it will show KeyError: